# I'm stuck on finding a word to say "you can try anything" or "anything goes"

Tags: meaning

I'm stuck on finding a word to say  "you can try anything" or "anything goes".

For context, I mean a word to tell a street kid or poor child who goes to a grand buffet for the first time that s/he can eat anything they want, and that they can have as much of anything that they want.

Comment: Please add a sentence where you might use it!

Comment: What @Josh61 said. Without *far* more context I don't see how this question could possibly have a single unambiguously correct answer.

Comment: Sure. Whatever.

Comment: 'You have carte blanche.'

Comment: How about *You can eat anything you want and  have as much of anything that you want*?

Answer (score 0):

The world is filled with possibilities.
From Dr. Seuss : "Oh the places you can go!"
The sky is the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Uninhibited: not limited or restricted

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/uninhibited

The guests at the party were uninhibited and soon naked.

Answer (score 0):

**laissez–faire**

> :  a philosophy or practice characterized by a usually deliberate
>   abstention from direction or interference especially with individual
>   freedom of choice and action
>
> Merriam-Webster